# In python, bash, or perl, how can I artificially inflate my memory

Tags: python, memory

Hopefull really simple.  I want to artifically inflate my memory... i'm doing this for testing purposes...   Any way in linux would be fine.

Comment: Do you mean allocate/use up memory?

Comment: yes, not to the point where i'm gonna crash but up to 99% usage is fine

Answer (score 7):

Python:

```
x = [0]
while True: x.extend(x)
```

This will double the size of `x` until memory runs out (you get `MemoryError`).

Answer (score 2):

Just make a string. There are only a few extra bytes overhead, and very fast because the memory is all allocated at once

```
dummy = ' '*num_bytes_to_use_up
```

There's no portable way to ask how much free memory there is

under linux you can look at/parse `/proc/meminfo`

```
>>> open('/proc/meminfo').readlines()[1]
'MemFree:         1248940 kB\n'
>>> dummy = ' '*1000000000
>>> open('/proc/meminfo').readlines()[1]
'MemFree:          271472 kB\n'
>>> del dummy
>>> open('/proc/meminfo').readlines()[1]
'MemFree:         1243464 kB\n'
```

Comment: Well, because the amount of free memory depends on whether you use it or not (in most modern OSes). If you don't use the memory, you can have 20TB of free memory for all the OS cares.